# How to create/genrate pptx or pdf file in flutter app

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

How can i genrate pdf or pptx file in flutter app

Chat gpt tells that i can do it with pptx package but there is no such package available

Comment: Hi, can you please provide code that you tried for creating PDF files? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use these packages to create pdf from flutter.

https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf

Here is a sample example of using pdf package

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

Future<void> main() async {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      build: (pw.Context context) => pw.Center(
        child: pw.Text('Hello World!'),
      ),
    ),
  );

  final file = File('example.pdf');
  await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
}
```